# Django - Can't import app names - Unresolved Reference

Tags: python, django

I'm starting with a project and I suddenly can't import App names. **PyCharm** says that app is `Unresolved Reference` and when I try to start shell and import app, it says that it's unrecognized.

Do you know where could be the problem? I've checked whether the correct `venv` is activated.

[image]

SHELL:

```
>>> from ProductSpyWeb import Api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Api
```

**APPS in Settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MainApp',
    'Api',
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `import Api` - the same way you just have `Api` in `INSTALLED_APPS` instead of `ProductSpyWeb.Api`.

Assuming that you aren't doing anything strange with your Python path, when you use `from ProductSpyWeb import Api` from the Django shell it's trying to import from `ProductSpyProject/ProductSpyWeb/ProductSpyWeb/Api`.

Comment: It was one of two problems. The second problem was that PyCharm messed up unresolved imports (the imports above was correct). I changed src directory and it works.

Comment: @Milano over three years later, I was running into the same issue, and your PyCharm src directory comment fixed the problem for me. Thank you!